# Which column(s) should I create an index on?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

How to create by depend on this select statement.

```
SELECT 
      A.FUSERID, A.FNAME, B.FORGNAME, C.FAREA
FROM 
      TBL_USERPROFILE A 
INNER JOIN 
      V_ORGANISATION B ON A.FORG = B.FORGID 
INNER JOIN 
      V_USER_AOE C ON A.FUSERID = C.FUSERID 
INNER JOIN 
      aspnet_UsersInRoles D ON C.FUSERID = D.UserId 
INNER JOIN 
      aspnet_Roles E ON D.RoleId = E.RoleId
WHERE 
      E.RoleName = 'applicant'
```

It is right to create like this??

```
Create index index.B on TBL_Userprofile A (A.FUSERID, A.FNAME, B.FORGNAME, C.FAREA)
```

Comment: You definitely also want to have indices on all the foreign key columns in your tables.

Comment: I hope whoever created the convention that all columns (sometimes miscalled fields) should have names starting with `F` is now seeing the pointlessness of such a convention...

Comment: @Damien FI fdon't fthink fyou funderstand fthe frequirement, fthen!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of suggested indexes with included columns.

```
A.Forg, Fuserid (INCLUDE FNAME)
B.ForgID (INCLUDE ForgName)
C.FuserID (INCLUDE FAREA)
D.UserID, RoleID
E.RoleID, RoleName
```

This will cover all your `JOIN`s, and the result fields are `INCLUDE`d with the `JOIN` keys so there's no lookup involved - the leaf node will have the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this index:

```
create index index_B on aspnet_Roles(RoleName)
```

Comment: i means from that select statement...with combine multiple table.how to do index. or i need to create one by one index for each table involved??? please guide me...

Comment: @helmi No I think you have misunderstood how indexes are used. First you create them in your database. Then sql-server will use it whenever it can, i.e. when there is a query that would benefit from it.

Comment: Indexing on RoleName probably isn't going to do any good. There are probably less than 10 role names, so there isn't a lot of uniqueness in the values for an index to help much. More than likely, the Roles table will just end up being a table scan.